# Simplify a long namespace for impl when importing the type would introduce ambiguity?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to simplify namespace for the following code?

```
struct T {...}

impl<'a> From<A::B::C::D::Foo<'a>> for T {
    fn from(x: A::B::C::D::Foo<'a>) -> Self {
        T {...}
    }
}
```

I don't want to `use A::B::C::D::Foo` in the current module as `Foo` might bring in namespace ambiguity.

Is there a way to temporarily/locally `use A::B::C::D::Foo` for the `impl`? It seems I can only do that within a function scope, rather than an `impl` scope.

Currently, my workaround is to use a dummy module.

```
struct T {...}
mod abc {
    use super::T;
    use A::B::C::D::Foo;


    impl<'a> From<Foo<'a>> for T {
        fn from(x: Foo<'a>) -> Self {
            T {...}
        }
    }
}
```

If using a nested module is the canonical solution, is it possible to define an anonymous module since the module name is unimportant?

Note, I don't mind writing `A::B::C::D::Foo` once for `impl`, but since the type in `from` is the same as the one in `impl From`, I am looking for ways to NOT have to write the same `A::B::C::D::Foo` twice.

Answer (score 3):

> as `Foo` might bring in namespace ambiguity

You can rename the type when you import it to avoid ambiguity:

```
pub mod a {
    pub mod b {
        pub mod c {
            pub mod d {
                pub struct Foo;
            }
        }
    }
}

struct T;

use a::b::c::d::Foo as UniqueName;

impl<'a> From<UniqueName> for T {
    fn from(_: UniqueName) -> Self {
        T
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

You could also use a *type alias*:

```
type UniqueName = a::b::c::d::Foo;
```